# Could not cast value of type ‘NSNull’ (0×106a4f520) to ‘NSDictionary’

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my project on github: 
https://github.com/alshfu86/Recipes

I have one problem. If I remove something from my Firebase database I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type ‘NSNull’ (0×106a4f520) to ‘NSDictionary’ (0×106a4ef58).

in method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for:indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
    let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let title = rowData["title"] as! String
    cell.recipeLabel.text = title.uppercased()
    let imageUrl = rowData["youtubeID"] as! String
    let imageQuality = rowData["imageQuality"] as! String
    let urlPath = youtubeBaseImageURL + imageUrl + "/" + imageQuality + ".jpg"
    let url = URL(string: urlPath)
    cell.recipeImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
    print("uString(describing: rl )path = \(String(describing: url))")
    return cell
}
```

here is all class:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    var data = [Any]()
    var categoryTitle = ""

    let youtubeBaseImageURL = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //is the device landscape or portrait
    var isPortraid = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"chevron"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.title = categoryTitle

        print("data: \(self.data)")

        //  loadAdmobBanner()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.orientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            isPortraid = false
        }
    }

    func orientationChanged(){
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            isPortraid = false
        } else {
            isPortraid = true
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func back(){
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for:indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        let title = rowData["title"] as! String
        cell.recipeLabel.text = title.uppercased()
        let imageUrl = rowData["youtubeID"] as! String
        let imageQuality = rowData["imageQuality"] as! String
        let urlPath = youtubeBaseImageURL + imageUrl + "/" + imageQuality + ".jpg"
        let url = URL(string: urlPath)
        cell.recipeImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        print("uString(describing: rl )path = \(String(describing: url))")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let playerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerViewController") as! PlayerViewController
        let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        let youtubeUrl = rowData["youtubeID"] as! String
        playerViewController.urlPath = youtubeUrl
        let ingredients = rowData["ingredients"] as! String
        playerViewController.about = ingredients

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playerViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if isPortraid {return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/5
        } else {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/5.2
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToCategory(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    }
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: on line:  let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

Comment: `cellForRow` is the wrong place to filter the `null` data. You should do that while loading the data. And – as always – don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift

Answer (score 0):

The error must be on this line:

```
let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
```

The error is that the array contains some null values (represented as `NSNull`). You should probably do a conditional cast, i.e.:

```
if let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary { 
    // do stuff here
}
```

---

Or alternatively, declare `data` as an array of dictionaries:

```
var data = [NSDictionary]()
```

then filter out the null values before assigning them to `data`:

```
self.data = yourdatasource.filter { $0 is NSDictionary }
```

Then later simply retrieve the element:

```
let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row]  // do stuff here
```

Comment: can you give me some ex. of filter?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: if I try use                   if let rowData = self.data[indexPath.row] { 
    // do stuff here
} Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSDictionary'

Comment: Im relay sorry but it still problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was my problem (the if-let is no longer needed), I edited the answer. Does it now work?

Comment: no look if I use self.data = yourdatasource.filter { $0 is NSDictionary } in my code I get this type of error Cannot assign value of type '[(key: Any, value: Any)]' to type